# How do you display an alternative message if a checkbox is unchecked in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to display a message if a checkbox is checked or its unchecked. I thought using an if/else statement would work but I keep getting an error message that my variable is undefined whenever the checkbox is unchecked. What do I do to stop it?

This is my code on my html form

```
  <input type='checkbox' value='1' name='check_box_con'>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Order" />
```

And this is the code in my php file

```
  if ($_POST['check_box'] == '1') {
   print "they want a cookie";
   } else {
      if ($_POST['check_box'] !== '1') {
      print "they do not want a cookie";
      }
   }
```

What is wrong with this? Is there an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

your post key should be check_box_con

```
$_POST['check_box_con']
```

Comment: Pardon me, I made a mistake in the code, the names are the same in both my html and my php script and its still coming up with an error

Answer (score 0):

The name attribute will be the key of $_POSt array when the form is submitted.So you must use the same key in $_POST array to get the value of the elemnent.So `$_POST['check_box']` must be changed to `$_POST['check_box_con']`. You should change the code to this

```
if (isset($_POST['check_box_con']) && $_POST['check_box_con'] == '1') {
   print "they want a cookie";
} 
else {
   print "they do not want a cookie";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['check_box'] should be  $_POST['check_box_con']. Also, in else part there is no need of checking condition once again.

```
if (isset($_POST['check_box_con'])) {
    print "they want a cookie";
 } else {     
    print "they do not want a cookie";     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An unchecked checkbox is not sent in the POST request - you only get it if it's checked, so you could do this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['check_box_con'])) {
   print "they want a cookie";
 } else {
      print "they do not want a cookie";
 }
```